# basic android timer?

Tags: android, timer

I want the dialog box to pop up after 5 seconds. Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? Im getting an error in the Finish() section of the timer, (I've only been programmming for about three months now so please bear with my stupidity.

```
public void run() {
    CountDownTimer counter  = new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        public void onFinish() {
            if (count == value) {
                AlertDialog.Builder lost = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  //  <-----There is my error its telling me // to go and set up my dialog AlertDialog.Builder(new CountDownTimer(){}) {  And I dont understand it


                lost.setMessage("You lost! you are ugly!" +
                        "" +
                " new game?");
                lost.setCancelable(false);
                lost.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        clicks.setText("Clicks ");
                        count = 1;
                        generator = new Random();
                        value = generator.nextInt(100);
                        imgBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.push);
                    }
                });
                lost.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        generator = new Random();
                        value = generator.nextInt(100);
                        ButtonMasherActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                });

                lost.create();
                lost.show();
            }
        }

    };
    counter.start();
}
```

Comment: What type of error you got please provide show Log..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this :

```
AlertDialog.Builder lost = new AlertDialog.Builder(ButtonMasherActivity.this);
```

`AlertDialog.Builder` needs a `Context` object not a `CountdownTimer` object.

Comment: Ok so I can get rid of the count down timer completely?

Comment: Just replace the line where you are getting the error with the line I provided in my answer, you should be good to go.